# C - Modificar un struct desde un archivo

Tags: c, archivo, struct

acabo de empezar con C y no tengo ni idea la verdad. La cosa es hacer structs y meterlos en un archivo para luego leerlos y modificarlos. 
No Tengo ni idea de como hacer para modificar un struct del archivo en particular. Espero que me podais ayudar, soy un poco malo en esto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)


int const MAX=100;

typedef struct {

char name[256];
char email[256];
int number;
char adress[256];
int urgent;
time_t time;
} order;


void add();
void read();

int main() {

int a=0;
while (a != 4) {
    printf("type the number of the operation you would like to make\n");
    printf("1-Add new order\n");
    printf("2-List all orders\n");
    printf("3-Modify order\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);

    switch (a) {
    case(1): {add(); break; }
    case(2): {read(); break; }
    case(3): {}
    default: break;
    }
}

return 0;

}

void read() {

order pedido;
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("text.txt", "rb");

    while(fread(&pedido, sizeof(pedido), 1, fp)==1)
    {

    printf("\nName: %s", pedido.name);
    printf("\nEmail: %s", pedido.email);
    printf("\nNumber: %d", pedido.number);
    printf("\nAdress: %s", pedido.adress);
    if(pedido.urgent==1) printf("\nUrgent:yes");
    if (pedido.urgent==0) printf("\nUrgent:no");
    printf("\nTimeSys: %ld", pedido.time);
        printf("\n********************\n");
}
printf("\nFinished\n");

fclose(fp);
return;
}

void add()

{

order ord;
char temp[256];
printf("insert Order data\n");
printf("Name\n");
scanf("%s", &ord.name);
printf("Email\n");
scanf("%s", &ord.email);
printf("Phone number\n");
scanf("%d", &ord.number);
printf("Adress\n");
scanf("%s", &ord.adress);
printf("Urgent(y/n)\n");
scanf("%s", &temp);
if (temp[0]== 'y')
    ord.urgent= 1;
else if (temp[0] == 'n')
    ord.urgent = 0;
else {
    printf("error"); return;
}

time_t tiempo = time(NULL);
ord.time=tiempo;

FILE *sourcefile= fopen("text.txt", "a");


fwrite(&ord, sizeof(ord), 1, sourcefile);

fclose(sourcefile);

return;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> acabo de empezar con C y no tengo ni idea la verdad.

Entonces te sugiero que no uses cosas que no entiendes:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
```

Los warnings te avisan de que estás haciendo cosas que, si bien pueden funcionar, no son recomendables y pueden empezar a dar problemas en cualquier momento. Si silencias advertencias corres el riesgo de que tu flamante programa falle a la hora de presentarlo... estás avisado.

Por otro lado, te sugiero empezar a introducirte en C por cosas más sencillas... si has faltado a clase o no has prestado atención por la razón que sea te toca ponerte las pilas y recuperar el tiempo perdido... quejarse de que no tienes nivel no es una opción y es mejor que lo escuches ahora a que te des cuenta de ello a la hora de los exámenes.

> No Tengo ni idea de como hacer para modificar un struct del archivo en particular

Un `struct` únicamente existe en tu programa. Un fichero no es más que una secuencia de bytes... ahí no existen estructuras ni cadenas de caracteres ni números... solo son bytes y es tu programa el que sabe dar sentido a esa información.

Lo que te están pidiendo es que sepas localizar el registro a modificar, lo leas, apliques los cambios que te piden, y lo vuelvas a guardar en el fichero.

Leerlo ya sabes... lo estás haciendo con el método `read` y guardarlo también, método `write`... tienes casi todo hecho. Te falta incorporar una búsqueda. Tendrás que pedirle algun dato clave al usuario que te permita localizar el registro a modificar... por ejemplo el nombre:

```
char nombre[255];
print("Indica el nombre a buscar: ");
scanf("%s,nombre);
```

Y después de esto vas leyendo todos los registros hasta que encuentras uno cuyo nombre coincide con el pedido. Nota que los flags con los que abrimos el fichero son diferentes a los indicados en `read`. Esto es así porque necesitamos privilegios de escritura para modificar el fichero.

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("text.txt", "rb+");

while(fread(&pedido, sizeof(pedido), 1, fp)==1)
{
  if( strcmp(pedido.name,name) == 0 )
    break;
}

if( feof(fp) )
{
  puts("Nombre no encontrado\n");
  fclose(fp);
  return; 
}

// Ya tenemos localizado el registro
```

Ahora le permites al usuario modificar algun parámetro...

```
printf("Correo actual: %s\n",pedido.email);
puts("Introduce nuevo correo: ");
scanf("%s",pedido.email);
```

Y guardas el registro en el fichero. Para ello lo primero que hay que hacer es retroceder el cursor del fichero al inicio del registro. Si no lo hacemos machacaremos un registro que no nos interesa tocar:

```
fseek(fp,-sizeof(order),SEEK_CUR);
fwrite(&pedido, sizeof(order), 1, fp);
```

Y ya hemos terminado... solo nos falta cerrar el fichero.

```
fclose(fp);
```